# How to get count along with rest of the fields in Pig?

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I have following data set.

```
f1,f2,f3,f4,f5,f6
```

I am looking for count of f6 along with rest of the fields.

f1,f2,f3,f4,f5,5

f1,f2,f3,f4,f5,3

and so on.

I tried this code but it takes too long to execute

```
A = LOAD 'file a'
B = GROUP A BY f6
C = FOREACH B GENERATE FLATTEN (group) as f6, FLATTEN(f1), FLATTEN(f2),FLATTEN(f3),FLATTEN(f4),FLATTEN(f5),COUNT(f6)
```

Is there any better way to achieve what I am looking for ?

If I simply try to get count without flatten then fields end up in bag but I want final output as tuple.

So trying this gives me output as bag

```
C = FOREACH B GENERATE FLATTEN (group) as f6, A.f1,A.f2.A.f3,A.f4,A.f5, COUNT(f6)
```

All inputs are appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: I tried following code to obtain desired output but don't know if this is equivalent of what @alexeipab mentioning below:

I actually have another relation after load statement that projects few fields from 'file a'.   So not sure what you suggesting will work ?
For now I used following pseudo code

     A = Load 'file a'

     B = FOREACH A GENERATE A.f1,A.f2,A.f4,A.f5,A.f6

     C=  GROUP B BY f6

     D = FOREACH B GENERATE FLATTEN group, COUNT(B)

     E = JOIN B BY f6, D BY f6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is also possible to flatten the projection which was grouped.

```
A = LOAD 'file a';
B = GROUP A BY f6;
C = FOREACH B GENERATE FLATTEN(A), COUNT(A) as f6_count;
```

EDIT 1:
The key is using FLATTEN(A) instead of FLATTEN(group).

FLATTEN(A) will produce a tuple with all of the columns from the original relation and will get rid of the bag, even those that were not used in the group by statement  (f1, f2, f3, f4, f5, f6).

FLATTEN(group) will return only columns used in the group by, in this case f6.
Advantage of this approach is that it is very efficient and requires a single Map Reduce job to execute. Any solution that involves JOIN operation adds extra Map Reduce job.

As a general rule of thumb in pig, hive and MR, group by and join operations usually are executed as separate MR Jobs and reducing the number of MR jobs leads to improved performance.

Comment: please see my edit above.  What you are mentioning gives same result ?

Comment: Result would be the same, but the performance will be worse, because of an extra join. Pig is not SQL, it has bags which open extra opportunities that improve performance. See EDIT 1 for details.